# How can I access the first row with a specific ID using SQL?

Tags: sql, database

I have a table containing a date for every time a person made a payment. Every person has a unique ID, and sometimes an ID has made many payments (which means several rows). 
How do I access the very first payment a person made if they made more than 1?

Comment: Having a payment date for each payment, ordering by that date, and limiting the query to 1 result (using LIMIT 0,1) is the most common approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming no one makes multiple payments on the same date, here is one approach in standard SQL:

```
select p.*
from payments p join
     (select personid, min(paymentdate) as minpd
      from payments
      group by personid
     ) pp
     on p.personid = pp.personid and p.paymentdate = pp.minpd;
```

Another approach is to use the ANSI standard window functions:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by personid order by paymentdate) as seqnum
      from payments
     ) p
where seqnum = 1;
```

This will return one row per person.  If you want duplicates, then use `rank()` rather than `row_number()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT top 1 *
FROM ...
WHERE ...
ORDER BY PaymentDate
```